# Chunked uploads with Rack

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm looking for some Rack middleware to handle chunked, resumable file uploads with progress monitoring. I've found [Upr](http://upr.bogomips.org/) which looks like it would handle the progress part perfectly, but can't find any docs on how to do chunked uploads with Rack. I know that Rack has Rack::Chunked, but haven't found any guidance on using it. Has anyone done something like this? Better yet: with Rainbows!?

Comment: After some more research, I'm perhaps even more confused. It seems like there are two basic approaches: Amazon's, wherein the client manually breaks the file into chunks, sends them in multiple PUT requests, and finalizes them with another request; and WebDAV's, which uses a single PUT with a Content-Range header.

The questions are: which is right? Which will be best supported? Why did Amazon break from the precedent set by WebDAV (I assume with good reason)? Are there any Rack modules that support either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no good standard with pre-existing Ruby code for doing this. The closest I've found is http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/ResumableHttpRequestsProposal which has a POC implementation linked at http://www.idle-hacking.com/2009/03/resumable-file-uploads/ .